# Moving along the simultaneous solution of two hypersurfaces without an explicit formula

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $F(\vec{x})$, $G(\vec{x})$ be two polynomials defined there.  Define a path $\mathbb{P}$ with endpoints $\vec{x}_0$ and $\vec{x}_f$ such that for all $\vec{x}_p \in \mathbb{P}$, $F(\vec{x}_p) = G(\vec{x}_p) = 0$.  Assume that I know the endpoints of the path (that is, I know two points at which the polynomials are simultaneously zero), but I do not have an explicit formula for the algebraic variety formed by the solution sets.  If I start at $\vec{x}_0$, is there a way to know in which direction(s) I can move and remain on the variety without knowing the variety explicitly?

Comment: I don't think I understand the question. If the only information you have is 2 points, there is no possible way to know the possible tangent directions to the variety at one of the points. Put differently, there are many possible varieties that contain those two points, and there will not be any tangent directions common to all the varieties.

Comment: I also know the polynomials themselves.  Sorry, I'm not exactly sure how to be precise here.  What I want is this: I know both F and G, and I know that at $\vec{x}_0$ they are both zero.  I also know that I cannot solve for an explicit formula for the variety itself, in general.  I want to be able to choose new points, starting at $\vec{x}_0$ and moving along the variety, so that every new point that is chosen is guaranteed to be on the variety.  Does that make more sense?